# Need some tips with a simple access program

Tags: sql, database

My program is very simple. I have created 4 tables. I opened a Created a Query Design and in SQL view I typed in the following....

```
SELECT product description, quantity,
FROM inventory
WHERE (quality<=10)
;
```

Basically I just want to show all the products that have 10 units or less, but it gives me an error that says "Syntax Error, (missing operator) in query expression 'product description'.
any help please?

Comment: Should `WHERE (quality<=10)` be `WHERE (quantity<=10)`?

Answer (score 1):

You almost certainly have a typo: `quality` should be `quantity` in the where clause.

If your column name has a space in it, use square brackets around it.

Also, you have an extra trailing comma in the selected columns clause that will cause a syntax error.

With everything corrected, it looks like this:

```
SELECT [product description], quantity
FROM inventory
WHERE quantity <= 10
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the space in Product Description. Try using square brackets around that column name:

SELECT [product description], quantity, etc